# Passing field values from subreport to main report in SSRS 2013

Tags: msbi

I am developing a report in SSRS 2013 in which i am trying to pass a column/Field values from subreport to Main Report as i have to use the value of the column/Field to display the row in other tablix of main report. Can some one help me with this.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Can you show the design of the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your textbox properties at **Action > Go to report**:

Passing a parameter to a subreport:

```
'Name
Parameter1Sub 'This is the name used in the subreport

'Value
[@Para1]

'In the expression
=Parameters!Para1.Value
```

If you want to pass a value from your tablix:

```
'Name
FieldNameSub 'This is the name used in the subreport

'Value
[FieldName.UniqueName]

'In the expression
=Fields!FieldName.UniqueName
```